# Showing more than 1 page of site collections

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, site-collection

I have over 200 site collections present and when I go into the admin page, I can see about ~50 or so of them and that's it. They're alphabetically ordered so I can see it's not getting past `p`. The site collections are there when I manually type in the URL for that site collection.

SharePoint is not giving me an arrow where I can look at the whole next page of site collections.

Is this a limitation of Sharepoint or can I do something to see the next page of site collections?

Answer (score 0):

When you go to View all site collection in admin page, you see the below screen.. Notice the 1-30 with an arrow alongside the URL of the web application, this will allow you to change page..

[image]

Comment: This is a multi-tenant system and I'm looking to do this inside the tenant admin site. So from this page I'm looking to get to the 'next page of collections'.

Here is a picture of the tenant admin site.

http://iforce.co.nz/i/imcx1xf3.144.png